# Splitting string with braces into array

Tags: php, arrays

How do I split the **OPTIONS** column into array where the index of the array will be digit in the string. For example, using this

```
[OPTIONS] => {0: 'phy','chem','bio'},{1: 'webtech','algo'}
```

will result to

```
Array
(
    [0] => [
        [0] => 'phy',
        [1] => 'chem',
        [2] => 'bio'
    ],
    [1] => [
        [0] => 'webtech',
        [1] => 'algo'
    ]
)
```

Index.php

```
<?php
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb','root','');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("Eror");
    }

    $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM table");
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);


    foreach ($data as $key) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($key);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
?>
```

**RESULT**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [ID] => 1
    [FACULTY_NAME] => APPLIED SCIENCE
    [DEPT] => SLT,COMPUTER SCIENCE,FOOD TECHNOLOGY,NUD,HMT,
    [OPTIONS] => {0: 'phy','chem','bio'},{1: 'webtech','algo'}
)
```

Comment: How did that options string come to be? This should have been a consideration *before* it ended up in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of different explodes and str_replace will get you the result.

I use both explode and multiexplode.
First I explode to the different subarrays, then I multiexplode the subarrays and the first value is the key and the rest is values, I split that with array_slice.

```
$str = "{0: 'phy','chem','bio'},{1: 'webtech','algo'}";

$arr = explode("},{", str_replace("'", "", $str));
foreach($arr as $a){
    $temp = multiexplode([": ", ","], str_replace(["{", "}"], "", $a));
    $res[$temp[0]] = array_slice($temp, 1);
}


var_dump($res);

function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {

    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return  $launch;
}
```

$res:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "phy"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "chem"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "bio"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "webtech"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "algo"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/YLLjI